# How to find the CDF of the binomial distribution in terms of an integral

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) says that the CDF of the binomial distribution in terms of the beta function can be expressed as

$$F(k;n,p)=Pr(X\leq k)=(n-k){{n}\choose{k}}\int_0^{1-p}t^{n-k-1}(1-t)^k {d}t$$

How to prove the equality? I don't quite have the access to the book referenced by the wiki page( Wadsworth, G. P. (1960). *Introduction to probability and random variables*. USA: McGraw-Hill New York. p. 52.)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2954501/321264.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using integration by parts we obtain:
$$F(k;n,p)=Pr(X\leq k)=(n-k){{n}\choose{k}}\int_0^{1-p}t^{n-k-1}(1-t)^k {d}t$$
$$=(n-k){{n}\choose{k}}\int_0^{1-p}(1-t)^k {d}\frac{t^{n-k}}{n-k}$$
$$=(n-k){{n}\choose{k}}\frac{1}{n-k}\left[(1-t)^kt^{n-k}|_0^{1-p}-\int_0^{1-p}t^{n-k}d(1-t)^k\right]$$
$$={{n}\choose{k}}\left[(1-1+p)^k(1-p)^{n-k}+k\int_0^{1-p}t^{n-k}(1-t)^{k-1}dt\right]$$
$$={{n}\choose{k}}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}+{{n}\choose{k}}k\int_0^{1-p}t^{n-k}(1-t)^{k-1}dt$$
$$={{n}\choose{k}}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}+{{n}\choose{k}}\frac{k}{n-k+1}\int_0^{1-p}(1-t)^{k-1}dt^{n-k+1}= etc.$$