# Asymptotic distribution

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. and $X_{(1)}<...<X_{(n)}$ be the order statistics.

Assume $X_i\sim Unif(0,1)$. For any fixed k, find the asymptotic distribution of $nX_{(K)}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

I know that density of $X_{(k)}$ is $f_{X_{(k)}}(x)=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}x^{k-1}(1-x)^{n-k}$. I'm not sure how to use this information.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3610536/find-the-asymptotic-distribution-of-nx-k/.