# Question about asymptotic distribution of order statistics.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Let $U_i$'s be i.i.d. Uniform$(0,1)$ random variables, and let $X_n = min\{U_1, \dots , U_n \}, Y_n = max\{ U_1 , \dots , U_n  \}, Z_n = Y_n - X_n $.
Then find asymptotic distribution of $n(1-Z_n)$.

I understand how to find asymptotic distribution of $X_n , Y_n$. But this problem makes me confused. Also I tried to use this method($X_{(r)} \sim Beta(r,n-r+1)$), but it failed.

Please help!

---

I know $Z_n=Y_n-X_n \sim Beta(n-1,2)$.
So, cdf of $Z_n$ is

> $P(Z_n \leq t) = n(n-1)\int_{0}^{t} x^{n-2}(1-x)dx$
>
> $P(1-Z_n \leq t) = 1-n(n-1) \int_{0}^{1-t}x^{n-2}(1-x)dx$
>
> $P(n(1-Z_n) \leq t) = 1-n(n-1)\int_{0}^{1-t/n}x^{n-2}(1-x)dx$

I don't know what to do after this.

Comment: did you mean $U_1, \dots, U_n$ instead of $X_1, \dots, X_n$?

Comment: Find the distribution of $Z_n$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33767/321264) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2830378/321264)) and hence cdf of $n(1-Z_n)$.

Comment: @tortue Oh, sorry. That's typo.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I understand your comment. Thx!

Comment: @StubbornAtom I'm sorry to bother you, but can you explain how to find cdf of that one?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I wrote down my thoughts, so can you check it for me?

Comment: Since $1-Z_n\sim \text{Beta}(2,n-1)$, the required asymptotic distribution is that of $nX_{(2)}$, which is shown here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3610536/321264. But for $nX_{(2)}$, that integral you have can be evaluated directly.

Comment: @StubbornAtom The link you gave me was very helpful. I'll think about it a little bit more. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

starting from your Range density that is a $Z_n\sim Beta(n-1;2)$ transforming your

$$Y_n=n(1-Z_n)$$

with usual technics:

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|$$

you get

$$f_{Y_n}(y)=\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot y\cdot \left(1-\frac{y}{n}\right)^{n-2}$$

whose limit results to me

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f_{Y_n}(y)=ye^{-y}$$

which is the density of a $Gamma(2;1)$

Comment: Did you mean that pdf of $Y = n(n-1)(y/n)(1-y/n)^{n-2} (1/n)$ because jacobian is 1/n?

Comment: @voidcome : no, it is not a $2\rightarrow 2$ transformation , Just use the univariate transformation theorem. See my edits. If my answer has been useful you can mark it as accepted